# How to add a word at the end of my sentence in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm pretty new in Python and I'm trying to make a simple code which returns evens numbers and the largest number i've introduced by command.

```
#! python3
lista = []
par = set()
num = int(input("Type a number: "))

while num >= 0:
    lista.append(num)
    num = int(input("Type a number: "))

print()
print(lista)
#print("%s %d" % ("The largest number you introduced is ",max(lista)))
print("The largest number you introduced is {lista:d}".format(lista = max(lista)))
print()

for i in lista:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        par.add(str(i)) 
        #print(i,end=" ")
print(sorted(par))
print("Even numbers are",", ".join(par),end=".")
```

The thing is I want It returns a msg like this: "The even numbers are 2, 4, 8, **and** 10."

I can't find the way to add an **and** at the end of my sentence. Can someone help me?

Comment: What error? Which line?

Comment: So the code doesn't return an error, you open an messagebox. That is a big difference. Why don't you simply test each error condition (or combination of conditions) separately. Now you first test **all** the conditions, and then start filtering them in different ways (first with a select case, then with if/then )